# How to colour the ocean?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make a map using `basemap()` function

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggOceanMapsData)
library(ggOceanMaps)

dt <- expand.grid(lon = c(-129, -124), lat = c(49, 53))
basemap(data = dt,land.border.col = "grey40")
```

I found a way to colour continents, but not the ocean.

I tried doing `theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "lightblue"))`, but it just overlays this layer on top of the graph, and I could not figure out how to transfer it at the back, so that the baseline map was visible.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if it's possible to fill the oceans with a single color by any command. Here's a workaround in which the colors for the bathymetry are all set to a single one.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggOceanMapsData)
library(ggOceanMaps)

dt <- expand.grid(lon = c(-129, -124), lat = c(49, 53))

basemap(data = dt, land.border.col = "grey40", bathymetry = T, legends = F) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c(rep("lightblue", 7)))
```

Comment: Thank you, would be a great trick if there were bathymetry data available for the entire ocean area.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately it does not fill all areas.

Comment: Nice hack @mgrund. The areas close to the land are not filled because the GEBCO bathymetry is not precise enough (and the resulting polygons are simplified to save space). To make this strategy work, one would need to create more detailed bathymetries. I suggested an alternative approach below. It has the benefit that it is simpler space-wise but you'll lose the grid lines. There is a way to manually add grid lines if one really wants them.

Answer (score 2):

You could also modify the ggplot2 background but then you'll lose the grid lines. A solution might be to hide them (second example). If you really want them, one can dig into the [map_cmd](https://github.com/MikkoVihtakari/ggOceanMaps/blob/8f3c83140346dee2a8b2e99e877ab8626017e724/R/map_cmd.R#L85) code to manually create them.

```r
library(ggOceanMaps)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
#> Loading required package: ggspatial
#> Setting data download folder to a temporary folder
#> /var/folders/fm/xtn13rlj7d3gp8twy7hh9prxtlq_m4/T//RtmprYybGO. This
#> means that any downloaded map data need to be downloaded again when you
#> restart R. To avoid this problem, change the default path to a
#> permanent folder on your computer. Add following lines to your
#> .Rprofile file: {.ggOceanMapsenv <- new.env(); .ggOceanMapsenv$datapath
#> <- 'YourCustomPath'}. You can use usethis::edit_r_profile() to edit the
#> file.'~/Documents/ggOceanMapsLargeData'would make it in a writable
#> folder on most operating systems.

dt <- expand.grid(lon = c(-129, -124), lat = c(49, 53))

basemap(data = dt) + 
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "lightblue"),
        panel.ontop = FALSE) 
#> Using lon and lat as longitude and latitude columns, respectively.
#> projection transformed from EPSG:4326 to EPSG:3995
```

[image]

```r
basemap(data = dt) + 
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "lightblue"),
        panel.ontop = FALSE,
        panel.grid = element_blank()) 
#> Using lon and lat as longitude and latitude columns, respectively.
#> projection transformed from EPSG:4326 to EPSG:3995
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-06-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>